# How do I know how much time battery has left on my MacBook?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, battery

macOS used to show how much time your battery was good for before it died (e.g. 4 hrs and 22 mins). I don't see it anymore though. Now it just gives a percentage. I'm running macOS Mojave 10.14 on a Macbook Pro.

Where can I find this info?

It used to appear under the menu bar battery icon as shown:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The macOS Sierra 10.12.2 update removed the ability to see the estimated time remaining, under the menu bar battery icon, on Macs equipped with a battery (various MacBooks). It is no longer possible to restore the functionality.

However, the same information can be obtained in the Activity Monitor app. Launch the Activity Monitor app using one of the following means:

- Go to Launchpad → Other folder → Activity Monitor.
- In Finder, go to Applications → Utilities → Activity Monitor.
- Search for Activity Monitor using Spotlight.

Once the app is launched, go to the Energy tab. The time remaining estimate is shown towards the bottom.

[image]

Comment: I did not know that it showed up in the activity monitor program. Thank you for your answer. Much appreciated!

Comment: The App store does offer some apps that add this back to the status icons (sorta), though not all are free and most (if not all) require a click to view the time-remaining stat.